# > Task :app:signReleaseBundle FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPM8y.png)

> Task :app:validateSigningRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file 'E:\QlSanPhamm\android\app\my-upload-key.keystore' not found for signing config 'release'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
504 actionable tasks: 26 executed, 478 up-to-date

I have tried everything to fix it but the error still appears.

Comment: Have you checked this 'E:\QlSanPhamm\android\app\my-upload-key.keystore'? . Make sure there is  keystore file with same name (my-upload-key) located at this path: E:\QlSanPhamm\android\app